# Powershell ISE 3.0 Intellisense for other programming languages

Tags: powershell, javascript, powershell-ise, intellisense

I really love using *Powershell ISE* - something about it makes me want to work with it; everything just fits together well, and it is smooth.

Also I love the way intelligent autocomplete is integrated - it just feels clean and smooth and usable.

The only problem is that I primarily code in Javascript, PHP, and with software that was originally designed for Unix-like OS's - e.g. Apache, bash, even node.js is a hell of a lot more usable on Unix.

But programming inside of Powershell ISE is just so damn user friendly, I find myself really wanting to use it.

***My question is*:**

Does the possibility exist without too much pain of getting Intellisense for other languages like Javascript or Node or PHP, etc. to work like the Intellisense in Visual Studio and ISE?  In other words - importing language files to provide the same functionality as is currently provided for the editor including scope based completion, etc

Comment: Visual Studio supports Intellisense for multiple languages ([JS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx), [PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080060/php-intellisense-on-visual-studio-is-it-possible), etc.) but unlike VS, the PS ISE is specifically for PowerShell, so I doubt you'll find a way to import info for other languages into it, but hey maybe someone has a way. :)

Comment: I know VS does, and the style is good.  But using VS always feels like using a tank in museum.

Comment: There are entire museums dedicated to tanks. ;)  But if you want lots of features like importable Intellisense, then you'll need a more robust program with more features; and more features means a larger (feeling) program.  Anyhow, my vote is still NO there's no way to do it -- if you want to program in multiple languages, use an IDE that's meant for it (ie: VS). :)

Comment: I currently use Sublime Text - and I like it specifically because it is extremely lightweight and feature packed.  I just like the feel of the ISE a bit better.  Visual Studio is too much.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to modify the Intellisense library for the PowerShell ISE. Take a [look at this](http://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2013/07/05/powershell-tabcompletion-or-tabcompletion/). It's pretty complex, but it's possible.

Comment: Awesome answer.  It does look painful, but this is useful.

Comment: I thought it was pretty interesting. I stumbled across that today after seeing your question last week.

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense has been integrated into many coding environments.  Intellisense began long before Microsoft added it to the powershell ISE.  SciTE is a customizable text editor for which many have created intellisense libraries.  Netbeans (used primarily for Java dev) also includes intellisense and can be used for Javascript.  Now to be clear, Javascript is not Java despite the name sharing, but the IDE (netbeans) has javascript ability.

The point I'm trying to get across is that most widely used languages already have intellisense built into some editor, some where.  While the idea of multiple IDE/ISE's might seem like a distraction at first, each one is built for a purpose (netbeans for java, ISE for powershell).  You might also want to look into something called PowerGUI.  Microsoft copied a lot of design elements from PowerGUI and a lot of sysadmins prefer PowerGUI over the current ISE.

What I usually do when looking for an editor for a language is google it.  I google "intellisense editor $language" and usually find something cool.  Enjoy coding!

Comment: To be clear; it isn't intellisense I'm after as such.  I use Komodo Edit and Sublime Text both of which have adequate implementations of this.  I have the same general problem with Netbeans, Eclipse, and Aptana as I do with Visual Studio.  Your answer (including making sure I was clear on the difference between Java and Javascript) suggests that you didn't read the question, but only the title.  Don't do that.  It isn't helpful.

Comment: @user1167442 You shouldn't assume.

Comment: Ok...Fair enough.  Thank you for making sure I knew that Java was not Javascript.